# How to trigger multiple promotions from a single build in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

We are using the "promoted builds plugin". Our situation is that we have multiple components. Each component has a build. Upon a successful build, the "deploy to staging" promotion is triggered and the component is deployed to our staging server. Each component build also has a "deploy to production" promotion, which (as you would guess) deploys the component to our production server.

Currently, all the "deploy to production" promotions are manual. Someone needs to manually trigger the promotion to production after some sort of validation and sometimes we forget. Sometimes our components get out of sync. 99% of the time, we just want to make sure that production is the same as staging.

My goal is to create a one click solution that goes through all of our component builds and triggers the "deploy to production" promotion (if it hasn't already been promoted) on the latest build of each component. What is the best way to achieve this?

---

**EDIT:** Here is the script that we are using to locate all jobs with unpromoted builds. As mentioned in the comments, we don't want to automatically promote builds. This needs to be a manual process.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.plugins.promoted_builds.*
import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.*

def promotionName = "Released to PROD" 

def getLatestPromotion = { promotedProjectAction, promotionProcess ->
  if (!promotedProjectAction || !promotionProcess) {
    return
  }
  def allPromotions = promotedProjectAction.getPromotions(promotionProcess)
  if (allPromotions.size == 0) {
    println ''
    return 
  }
  def latestPromotion = allPromotions.get(allPromotions.size() - 1)
}

def jobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems()
def okJobs = []
def badJobs = []
def ignoredJobs = []
jobs.each { job ->
  def projectName = job.fullName
  // projects that end with '-build' are promotable
  if (!projectName.endsWith('-build')) {
    ignoredJobs += projectName
    return
  }

  def project = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(projectName)
  def lastBuild = job.lastBuild

  def promotedBuildAction = lastBuild.getAction(PromotedBuildAction)
  if (!promotedBuildAction) {
    ignoredJobs += projectName
    return 
  }
  def promotedProjectAction = project.getAction(PromotedProjectAction)
  if (!promotedProjectAction) {
    ignoredJobs += projectName
    return 
  }
  def promotionProcess = promotedProjectAction.getProcess(promotionName)

  def latestPromotion = getLatestPromotion(promotedProjectAction, promotionProcess)
  if (!latestPromotion) {
    ignoredJobs += projectName
    return 
  }

  if (latestPromotion.rootBuild.number != lastBuild.number) {
    badJobs += "${projectName} last build #${lastBuild.number} last promotion #${latestPromotion.rootBuild.number}"
  } else {
    okJobs += projectName
  }
}

if (badJobs.size() > 0) {
  println 'WARNING---These jobs have on STAGING, but not on PROD'
  badJobs.forEach { msg -> println '  ' + msg }
  println ''
}

println 'These jobs are up to date on PROD'
okJobs.forEach { msg -> println '  ' + msg }
println ''


println 'These jobs are not promoted to PROD and are ignored in this build'
ignoredJobs.forEach { msg -> println '  ' + msg }
println ''

if (badJobs.size() > 0) {
  throw new Exception("Found ${badJobs.size()} unpushed jobs.")
}
```

The result will be a list of builds that have been promoted to staging but are not yet in production. Afterwards, we manually click the "Promote" button for each of these, if it is necessary and safe.

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution to this problem?

Comment: We started working on a script that would traverse all of our builds, looking for a latest build that was not yet pushed to production. It was working a little bit, but we abandoned the approach since we decided that we always wanted manual intervention before promoting to production. I can share what we had of the script for you if you like.

Comment: that would be awesome; it might give me a lead on implementing what we're looking for. Thanks for the offer!

Comment: I added the script we are using now that finds all unpromoted builds. I hope this is a good start for you. To use this, create a new build and have that build invoke a groovy script. You can try out your groovy scripts in the groovy console in the admin section of jenkins.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!